# Sparse matrix factorization of A = Bᵀ·B

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have a sparse matrix `A`, and I want to compute a matrix `B` such that

```
B.T.dot(B) = A
```

Is there any function on `scipy` module that can do this? 
If not, is it possible in `numpy`?

Comment: It's not in scipy, but is [this](https://pythonhosted.org/scikits.sparse/cholmod.html) helpful?

Comment: What have you discovered in the `linalg` modules (for `numpy` and `sparse`)?  How about being more specific about the mathematical name of the desired operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is available in `numpy` and `scipy` for dense matrices and in `scikits.sparse` for sparse matrices, depending on your matrix. Is your matrix **positive definite**? Is it **symmetric**? If so, then you are essentially looking for a Cholesky decomposition.

```
>>> A = np.random.rand(100,100)  # Construct a dense matrix
>>> np.fill_diagonal(A,10) # Ensure the matrix is positive definite
>>> A = 0.5*(A+A.T) # Symmetrize the matrix
>>> B = np.linalg.cholesky(A) # Perform Cholesky decomposition 
>>> np.allclose(B.dot(B.T),A) # Verify
True
```

Normally `B` is a lower triangular matrix in `numpy`, but it is a good practice to be sure of this, as for an upper triangular matrix you need to change the multiplication order from `B.dot(B.T)` to `B.T.dot(B)`. With the `scipy` version there is the keywork argument `lower` (which is `False` by default) that you can specify to always get the right order that you need.

```
>>> B = sp.linalg.cholesky(A,lower=False)
>>> np.allclose(B.T.dot(B),A)
True
```

Although this should not be a big deal. For sparse matrices, you can either transform your sparse matrix to dense matrix with `todense()` or `toarray()` (not recommended) or use the `scikits.sparse` module

```
>>> from scikits.sparse.cholmod import cholesky
>>> spA = csc_matrix(A)
>>> factor = cholesky(spA)
>>> spB = factor.L()
>>> np.allclose(spA.todense(),spB.dot(spB.T).todense()) # Just for verification
True
```

For **semi-definite** matrices, there is also a Cholesky type factorization available in the paper: [Analysis of the Cholesky Decomposition of a Semi-definite Matrix](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1193/), but not implemented in `scipy` or `scikits`, as far as I know.